# Difference between specifying plid in opening tag and passing it as a param in Liferay

Tags: java, url, liferay, portlet

What is the difference between specifying the plid in the opening tag when creating a portlet url

`<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="myurl" windowState="normal" plid="123456">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="struts.portlet.action" value='/view/myAction' />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>`

and passing it as a param

`<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="myurl" windowState="normal">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="struts.portlet.action" value='/view/myAction' />
    <liferay-portlet:param name="plid" value='123456' />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>`

I get different error messages when the plid doesn't exist so I was wandering what the difference was

Comment: plid is not mandatory to be passed by either way in a case when you call action of the current portlet. What errors do you observe?

Comment: I know it's not mandatory, only asking out of curiosity. It says no layout exists with a number like that when I deliberately set it to the wrong one. I just want to know if there is a difference between the two ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the difference between specifying the plid in the opening tag and appending as request parameter when creating a portlet URL?

> **plid as tag-attribute:** There are two certainties, if any layout (page)
> for given plid is found on portal, then it will create URL specific to
> that page, otherwise plid will be appended as a queryString parameter.
>
> **plid as request-parameter:** In either case (correct / incorrect plid),
> plid will be appended as a queryString parameter with current layout
> URL with proper namespace of the portlet, which can be extracted from
> request object.

I get different error messages when the plid doesn't exist.

> Yes, certainly you will get, if there is no any layout / page found in your portal with the
> given plid.

so I was wandering what the difference was.

> The only difference can be the search for layout in case-1 before
> appending it to the URL on creation of renderURL by tag. While in case-2, plid is simply passed a
> request object that will be accessible in your portlet action.

Comment: @Prakash K: I have updated my answer, thanks for your detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q:** What is the difference between specifying the plid in the opening tag when creating a portlet url and passing it as a param

The main difference is:

- for **tag-attribute-plid** it would check for the plid and change your URL accordingly for that layout (page).
- and for **request-param-plid** it would simply append it to your URL (as a query-string) with proper namespace like other request params. Nothing special.

---

### Now an example

If **tag-attribute-plid** is used as follows inside your `my-portlet`:

```
<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="myurl" windowState="normal" plid="123456">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="struts.portlet.action" value='/view/myAction' />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>
```

When you want to construct a URL on a page-x to go to another page-y. Suppose you are on page: `Home` and you want to go to the `Help` page or to `Control Panel`, then in the `plid` attribute you would pass `pild` of `Help` page or `plid` of the `Control Panel`.

So if I pass the plid of Control Panel then the final URL would look something like:

> http://mylocalhost.com**/group/control_panel/manage**?p_p_auth=1g0RGj4L&p_p_id=my_WAR_myportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_my_WAR_myportlet_struts.portlet.action=%2Fview%2FmyAction

---

***The above is not achievable by passing the `plid` as a request param.***

---

> **Q:** I get different error messages when the plid doesn't exist so I was wandering what the difference was

Now you know what the difference is, so it might be easy to answer this.
If the **tag-attribute-plid** is **incorrect** it would create a URL something like this:

> http://mylocalhost.com**/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=123456**&p_p_auth .....

And if **request-param-plid** is **incorrect** it would create a URL for current page and append the plid, something like this:

> http://mylocalhost.com**/web/guest/home**?p_p_id=my_WAR_myportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_my_WAR_myportlet_struts.portlet.action=%2Fview%2FmyAction&**_my_WAR_myportlet_plid=123456**

Hope this helps.